# Conditional GROUP BY within a stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this block from a stored proc:

```sql
    IF (@ReportID = 212 OR @ReportID = 216)
    BEGIN
        SET @ShowCodes = 1

        INSERT INTO #tmprectype (ownerid, priorbalance, charges, assessment, AccountNumber, AssocName, adjustment, deposit, [return], payment, [address], ownerName, creditCode)
    
        -- SELECT columns
    
        FROM vOwnerLedgerByChg2 l WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN vOwnerPropertyAddress v WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.OwnerID = v.OwnerID
        INNER JOIN Association a WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.AssocID = l.AssocID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AssociationCharge g WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.AssocChgID = g.AssocChgID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN vallglhistory h ON h.AssocID = l.AssocID AND h.GlAccountID = g.GLAccountID
        WHERE l.AssocID = @AssocID 
        AND LedgerDate <= @Process 
        AND ISNULL(g.ChgTypeID, 0) = 6
        AND (ISNULL(@AssocChgID,0) = 0 OR l.AssocChgID = @AssocChgID)

        -- GROUP BY should be different depending on the @ReportID

        GROUP BY a.assoccode, a.assocname, l.associd, l.ownerid, v.ownername, v.propaddress, v.propcity, v.propstate, v.propzip, l.BKID, l.assocchgid, g.descr, l.AssocChgID, h.Code
        ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(8),a.assoccode) + CONVERT(varchar(16),l.ownerid), CASE WHEN ISNULL(l.BKID,0) > 0 THEN CASE WHEN l.assocchgid = -1 THEN 'Credit (Bankruptcy)' ELSE g.descr + ' (Bankruptcy)' END 
            ELSE CASE WHEN l.assocchgid = -1 THEN 'Credit' ELSE g.descr END END
    END
```

How can I conditionally `GROUP BY` depending on the `@ReportID`? If it's a `@ReportID = 212` I want to use the existing group by there, if the `@ReportID = 216` I want a different `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Do you mean you want a completely different group by in some situations? Doesn't also mean you would need different columns? Also, I notice you have a left join to AssociationChange but then in your where clause you have logically turned that into an inner join. Why not make that an inner join and include ChgTypeID as an additional join predicate?

Comment: Yeah, I want to group by differently (by address first for example, if the report ID is 216).

Comment: Then you would need different columns in the query right? Why not just use two queries? `If ReportID = 212 select query1 else select query2` or something along those lines

Comment: The clause in your `WHERE` against `g.ChgTypeID` should be in the `ON` and it shouldn't have an `ISNULL`; your method is not SARGable.

Comment: The NOLOCKs, they burn

Comment: That is a lot of effort to order your rows that you are inserting into a temp table. Does the order in the temp table truly matter? It looks like you don't have an identity on your temp table so I would say the order makes no difference. That order by is doing nothing but slowing down your code.

Comment: You can probably do something ugly, but why not just have different code for different reports. To simplify, you might turn the code into a view, it might save you a few keystrokes

Comment: The *order by* is completely redundant overhead here btw, a table does not know or care about any inserted order.

Comment: @siggemannen I agree but have to caution about turning this into a view. Given the names of couple things I have a feeling this is already referencing at least two views. And nested views are simply terrible for performance. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: We use this stored proc to feed data into a report designer that generates the format. I'm trying to re-use the same stored proc to order the data in a different way depending on the reportID. From the feedback here it looks like I would nee to just create another select query for it. Was hoping to avoid redundancy since the only difference would be the GROUP BY clase but so be it.

Comment: `IF (@ReportID = 212 ) ... end`  then another   `IF (@ReportID = 216) ... end`  otherwise you enter the realm of "dynamic sql" and that is not a place you want to be.

Comment: @SeanLange It's not nested views per se, it's the fact views are often too complex with too many extraneous joins, and when you combine them you just complicate things even more.

Comment: So what is this `GROUP BY` that you want? Perhaps they can be combined.

Comment: @Charlieface you should check out the link I posted. Grant Fritchey does a great job of explaining why nested views cause major performance issues, even with simple queries. But yes the more complex the views the more likely it is to get worse.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Sometimes dynamic sql is exactly where you want to be - don't go out of your way to make people even more afraid of it. If there are 327 different reports and they all differ by simple things like the columns in the group by ... I don't want to have to maintain 327 different but almost identical versions of the query (especially if it's prone to minor adjustments later, which will have to be made 327 times).